# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetLayer'

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, attributeerror

Using: QGIS 2.18 with a plugin: ECOPLAN Scenario evaluator, inserting self-made shapefiles made in Arcmap.

Received this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:/Users/PAU-EXT-LOVE/.qgis2/python/plugins\ECOPLAN_SE\ecoplan_se.py", line 7123, in runScenario
                CreateScenarioMask(ShpFile, RasterFile, GeoDbLandcover)
              File "C:/Users/PAU-EXT-LOVE/.qgis2/python/plugins\ECOPLAN_SE\ecoplan_se.py", line 266, in CreateScenarioMask
                SourceLayer = SourceShapefile.GetLayer()
            AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetLayer'

I have no knowledge of coding. Meaning I am not helped with previous answers.
**What can I do to prevent this error?** What does this mean?